# echart cannot be visualized on DOM even though there is an instance on checking inspect element

Tags: javascript, echarts

I have a weird issue that the `echarts` is not loading even though there is an instance on the DOM. I want to load it inside a widget. It works fine otherwise.
[no chartdissplayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjNEA.jpg)
[chart displayed in html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQBeH.jpg)

My chart code:

```
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('displayarea')); 
var option = {
    title: {
        text: 'ECharts '
    },
    tooltip: {},
    legend: {
        data:['aa']
    },
    xAxis: {
        data: ["aa","bb","cc","dd","ee","ff"]
    },
    yAxis: {},
    series: [{
        name: 'rr',
        type: 'bar',
        data: [5, 20, 36, 10, 10, 20]
    }]
};
myChart.setOption(option);
```

Can anyone guide me on what could be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

From Apache ECharts documentation:

> To be noticed, before calling *echarts.init*, you need to make sure the container already has width and height.
> If the height and width of the container do not exist, or you wish the chart size not equal to the container, you can initialize the size at the beginning.

So either define your div with width and height:

```
<div id="displayarea" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Or pass the desired size as an argument to *echarts.init*:

```
var myChart = echarts.init(
   document.getElementById('displayarea'),
   {width: 600, height: 400}
);
```